# How to redirect if subdirectory includes hash Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

At the request of the SEO specialist, I need to implement the following functionality.
I have to redirect if the link contains a capital letter.
For example https//domain.com/#Contacts ==> https//domain.com/#contacts.

In Nuxt I implemented with by creating function on server.js file which located on middleware folder.

But it doesn't work if path contains hash(#)

```js
export default function (req, res, next) {
    const url = req.url;

    if (url !== url.toLowerCase()) {
        res.writeHead(301, { Location: url.toLowerCase() });
        res.end()
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

I would be grateful if you answer or help

Comment: What does it do when the path contains a hash character?

Answer (score 0):

The part after the hash ([fragment identifier](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment)) is never going to be sent to the server by your browser, so what you're trying to do is impossible using redirects.

You can access them on the client-side, but I don't think that it would do any good in terms of SEO.

Comment: Thank you @kamil-bęben for your answer, I realized it on the client side. So now another problem accrued, I have to pass HTTP status code: 301.